# 400 Bad Request Error using URLFetchApp and Google sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, http-status-code-400, urlfetch

I have the below script, that is returning a 400 - bad request.

```
function createIssue(e)
{

  var url = "https://jira.xxxx.com/rest/api/2/issue/";
  var data = {'fields': { 
              'project': {'key':'DWH'},
              'summary':'Resttest',
              'description':'test',
              'issuetype':{ 'name': 'Data Requests'},
              'components':[{ 'name':'Data Warehouse'}],
              'fixVersions':[{ 'name':'NA'}] }};

  var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
  Logger.log(payload);
  var headers = 
  { 
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  };

  var options = 
  { 
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'method': 'POST',
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
    'headers': headers,
    'payload': payload
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var rc = response.getResponseCode();
  var responseText = response.getContentText();
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var issueKey = dataAll.key
  Logger.log(dataAll)
 }
```

I have tested out the actual payload via cURL and it was working, so Is there something else I am missing with this script?

Thanks a million for any assistance.

Best,
Neil

EDIT:

```
The curl command :
curl -D- -H
"Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxx1bXBraW5zMDQh" -X POST --data
"{ """fields""": { """project""": { """key""": """DWH""" }, """summary""": 
"""REST test 11111.""", """description""": """test""", """issuetype""": { 
"""name""": """Data Requests""" }
,"""components""":[{ """name""":"""Data Warehouse"""}] , """fixVersions""": 
[{"""name""":"""NA"""}]} }" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
https://jira.xxxxxxxxx.com/rest/api/2/issue/
```

I was doing some further reading and it appears that the google apps scripts are run from the google servers.  My jira instance is behind a company intranet, and as such not accessible from googles servers.  I also note a useIntranet feature that is depreciated.  Is there any way around this?

Many thanks,
Neil

Comment: Can you provide the worked curl sample and the document of API?

Comment: Try not stringifying the payload

Comment: If your address is not public, you can't ping it from Google Apps Script. No way around that, unless you deploy as a webapp or sidebar and use client side JavaScript.